# Android power on led notification, without notification?

Tags: java, android

First, sorry for my English, I'm Brazilian.

I have tried everything, and the most relevant code I found was using a module of the xposed framework, and it needs super user access to install the binaries in the system and the module.

Module: http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.semon.cameranotify
It turns on the led when the camera is in use and without entering a notification.

The apk descompiled java code:

```
package com.semon.cameranotify.mod;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.ClassNotFoundError;

public class LedServiceHook {
    public static final String ACTION_CHANGE_LED = "com.semon.cameranotify.change_led";
    private static final String CAMERA_ENABLE = "mCameraEnable";
    private static final String CLASS_BATTERY_SERVICE_LED = "com.android.server.BatteryService$Led";
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.systemui";
    private static final String TAG = "LedServiceHook";
    private static Object mBatteryLed = null;
    private static BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(LedServiceHook.ACTION_CHANGE_LED)) {
                LedServiceHook.changeLedColor(intent.getBooleanExtra("enable", false));
            }
        }
    };
    private static final int mCameraOpenedColor = -16711936;

    private static void changeLedColor(boolean enable) {
        if (mBatteryLed != null) {
            try {
                Object batteryLight = XposedHelpers.getObjectField(mBatteryLed, "mBatteryLight");
                if (batteryLight == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (enable) {
                    XposedHelpers.setAdditionalInstanceField(mBatteryLed, CAMERA_ENABLE, Boolean.valueOf(true));
                    XposedHelpers.callMethod(batteryLight, "setColor", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(mCameraOpenedColor)});
                    return;
                }
                XposedHelpers.setAdditionalInstanceField(mBatteryLed, CAMERA_ENABLE, Boolean.valueOf(false));
                XposedHelpers.callMethod(batteryLight, "turnOff", new Object[0]);
                XposedHelpers.callMethod(mBatteryLed, "updateLightsLocked", new Object[0]);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                XposedBridge.log(t);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void init(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        try {
            Class<?> batteryServiceClass = XposedHelpers.findClass(CLASS_BATTERY_SERVICE_LED, classLoader);
            XposedBridge.hookAllConstructors(batteryServiceClass, new XC_MethodHook() {
                protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    LedServiceHook.mBatteryLed = param.thisObject;
                    Context context = (Context) XposedHelpers.getObjectField(XposedHelpers.getSurroundingThis(param.thisObject), "mContext");
                    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                    intentFilter.addAction(LedServiceHook.ACTION_CHANGE_LED);
                    context.registerReceiver(LedServiceHook.mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
                }
            });
            XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(batteryServiceClass, "updateLightsLocked", new Object[]{new XC_MethodHook() {
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    Object cameraEnableObj = XposedHelpers.getAdditionalInstanceField(LedServiceHook.mBatteryLed, LedServiceHook.CAMERA_ENABLE);
                    if (cameraEnableObj != null && ((Boolean) cameraEnableObj).booleanValue()) {
                        param.setResult(null);
                    }
                }
            }});
        } catch (ClassNotFoundError e) {
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            XposedBridge.log(t);
        }
    }
}
```

The [LightsService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e098050/services/java/com/android/server/LightsService.java) from system package `com.android.server` contains the native methods for change led.

**Does anyone know of any brilliant ideas for possible ways to call methods of this class (LightsService.java)?**